# "Not In" does not work correctly in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a code in my stored procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[add_codes](@codes code_type readonly, @id int)as
    insert into codes(code,value) 
           select code,'' value from @codes
           where code not in (select code from codes)
```

this should only insert the new values, ignoring duplicates but it does not and after some inserts when I check the count of **code** and **distinct code** they have different values. what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you have any `null` values in either set?

Comment: no, there can be null values

Comment: Any reason you're not doing this as a `left join`?

Comment: And are there any duplicates in `@codes`?

Comment: well i don't know how to do that can you help? by the way what can be possibly wrong with this code, i double checked the codes and there are no null values

Comment: yes there are duplicate in @codes

Comment: I tried distinct selecting from @codes but didn't work

Comment: Show everything in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: What is the data type of your Code column in Codes and in the Table Data Type @Codes ?

Comment: the data type of code is varchar. I put the whole stored procedure code in the question

Comment: If two different people (or processes) are trying to insert codes with the same value, what happens? Is a lock held on the entire table while doing this INSERT (to ensure the SELECT gets the most recent committed data)?

Comment: What is the structure of type code_type declared as?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NOT IN` *should* work, but for something as simple as this, you could do something like:

```
INSERT INTO codes (code, value) 

SELECT DISTINCT
            code,
            '' AS value

FROM        @codes AS n

LEFT JOIN   codes AS c
    ON      n.code = c.code

WHERE       c.code IS NULL
```

Of course, it would be worthwhile to have a `UNIQUE` constraint set on the table *as well*.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN` *does* work.  If there is a single `NULL` value in `codes`, then `NOT IN` behaves a bit counter-intuitively.  It *works*, but it works by always returning "false".  That is because `NULL` is not a specific value, but an unknown value.

You should protect your code against this, if you use `not in`:

```
create procedure [dbo].[add_codes](@codes code_type readonly, @id int)
as begin
    insert into codes(code,value) 
           select code,'' value from @codes
           where code not in (select code from codes where code is false);
end;
```

I strongly agree with Rowland that the right way to approach this is with a `unique` constraint on the column that you want to be unique.